# external api handling in the backend

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios, backend

On my express server I make queries to an external API using its own token. When I log in to my server I request a token to the external API based on the user who logged in, and I keep the token of the external API in the token of my express server.

Each user gets different data according to their token from the external api, for queries that require external API information, I read the received token and get the external API token to send it through headers with axios, for example:

```js
const LoginUser = (request, response) {
  axios.post('/ExternalApi/auth',request.body)
  .then( data =>{
    const payload = {
      ...
      tokenExternalApi: data.token
    }
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, ...)
    return response.status(200).json(token)
  })
}

const getData = (req, response){
  const tokenFromClient = req.headers.authorization      
  //Function  extract tokenExternalApi from payload Token
  const tokenExternalApi = getTokenExternl(tokenFromClient ) 
  axios.get(`/urlExternalApi`, { headers: 
  { Authorization: tokenExternalApi }}
  ).then(res => {
    return response.status(200).json(res.data)
  })
}
```

Is this the correct approach to managing external apis tokens or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion, this seems to be a clean approach.

But keep in mind that tokens are visible to users, so the fact is your users can decode the token, view tokenExternalApi, know that you are using an external API in the backend and directly make calls to ExternalApi using that token, provided they have the know-how of it. If you understand this fact and are fine with it, then this works.

Otherwise, you can consider encoding the token before sending it to the user or store it on the server-side session.

Comment: Drawback of sharing the external API token is that the user may be able to make unlimited calls, which could put at risk the usage fees. The advantage is that you can query data directly from the client side, while still having only a short-lived token.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my sample code that I use for hit an external API within function in node js using axios

first time you should install axios `npm install axois`

```js
const axios = require('axios');

async yourFunction(){
  axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "http://yoururl.com",
      data: {
        name: '+62'+phoneNumber,
        number: '+62'+phoneNumber,
        message: 'success',
      }
  });
}
```